# When did MoDeans burn down?

Tags: letterkenny

My wife and I have been binge watching LetterKenny on Hulu.  At one point the group starts commenting about needing a bar in town.  It's later mentioned in Season three's episode "Bradley is a Killer" that the previous bar had burned down.  Until that scene, as far as I can remember, there was no mentions of MoDeans burning down.

Was this information deliberately left out of the show?  Did I miss a line somewhere?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Letterkenny/comments/aac31i/what_happened_to_modeans/ , https://www.reddit.com/r/Letterkenny/comments/ag4j1u/what_happened_to_modeans_between_season_1_and_2/ ,... "In real life: they lost that bar as a shooting location, so they kinda plug it being burnt down as a way to show viewers it's gone for good."